# Where is the Minimum Password Length Policy information stored on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm aware that the Minimum Password Length policy can be set through it can be set via Security Policies for windows 10, but once set is it stored as a registry value or somewhere else?

This help page, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/minimum-password-length, gives the location as 'Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Password Policy' but I can't see that as a file or registry location.

Comment: The documentation describes the group policy itself and can be view with the group policy editor.  You would have to view the documentation on the policy itself to identify the registry location that is modified when the policy is set.  Edit your question to include which edition of Windows 10 you are using.

Comment: That path given is in group policy editor, open a run box and type gpedit.msc and hit enter. Gpedit is not available in home and lower versions.

Comment: [here](https://media.askvg.com/articles/images2/Disable_Windows_Server_Password_Complexity_Requirements.png) is the location of the policies in question by the way.

Comment: Here is where it is stored in the registry possibly....https://serverfault.com/a/703339

Comment: Also see this....https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/80805-specify-maximum-minimum-pin-length-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 2):

> I'm aware that it can be set via secpol for windows 10, but once set is it stored as a registry value?

It is indeed stored in the registry.  You can also change it with `net accounts /minpwlen:7 in an elevated command prompt.

You can view the current value by using `net accounts` in an elevated command prompt.  The default value for an AD domain is going to be 7 characters.

> This help page, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/minimum-password-length, gives the location as 'Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Password Policy' but I can't see that as a file or registry location

The help page indicates the location of the group policy within the group policy editor.

> [image]

Source: [Customize the Password Policy in Windows 10/8/7](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/customizing-the-password-policy-in-windows-7)

As for the location within the registry.  It would be located within the following location.

> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SeCEdit\Reg Values\MACHINE/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/Netlogon/Parameters/`

There is a strong possability the value is stored in multiple locations.  While it exists in the above key, you would want to modify `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Network\MinPwdLen`, if you are looking to change the value of the Minimum Password Length policy itself.

Source:

- [Registry path for password complexity and storing passwords using reversible encryption](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/e0a5530f-ecb7-4e1a-98d3-c422dcbb3921/registry-path-for-password-complexity-and-storing-passwords-using-reversible-encryption?forum=winservergen)
- [Minimum password length](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/minimum-password-length)

Comment: If this machine is connected to an AD domain, changing the registry key, will not update the policy.  The next time the AD domain controller enforces the policies the key will set to the correct value.  **If this is indeed the AD domain controller use the group policy editor instead.**

Answer (score 1):

The minimum password length was since always stored in the registry for both
system-wide and per-user. I believe this is still the case for Windows 10.

- User Key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Network`
- System Key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Network`
- Value Name: `MinPwdLen`
- Data Type: REG_BINARY (Binary Value)

Answer (score -1):

Just to complete the comments of Ramhound and Moab, the path `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Password Policy` is the one given in the Local Group Policy Editor, that you can find by searching:

| edit group policy | **OR** | `gpedit.msc` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: edit group policy] |  | [image: gpedit.msc] |

[image: Local Group Policy Editor]